# How to check whether a minor mode(.e.g flymake-mode) is on?

Tags: emacs, flymake

I always get error when use flymake-mode. And flymake-mode turn off.

[image]

So I want to check whether flymake-mode is on. If it is not on, I will turn it on before call flymake-next-error.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're getting an error when you turn it on, what do you plan to gain from checking?

Comment: According to its homepage (http://flymake.sourceforge.net/), flymake is a minor mode, not a major mode.

Comment: Thanks. The error does not occurre all the time. It occurred When my js file has a lot of failed. And flymake is a minor mode.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Most minor modes are defined using the `define-minor-mode` macro. For buffer-local modes, that macro creates a buffer-local variable of the same name as the mode itself<sup>1</sup>. The variable is non-`nil` when the mode is enabled for the current buffer.

Therefore to check whether `flymake-mode` is enabled, you can test the variable `flymake-mode` (noting that this variable might not be defined at all if the mode has not been enabled):

```el
(and (boundp 'flymake-mode) flymake-mode)
```

Which, as Thom point out in the comments, can be expressed using the convenient macro:

```el
(bound-and-true-p flymake-mode)
```

Which we can use as the condition for an `if` or `when` or `unless` expression:

```el
(if (bound-and-true-p flymake-mode)
    (message "flymake-mode is on")
  (message "flymake-mode is off"))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For global minor modes, the corresponding variable is global; but flymake-mode is buffer-local.

Comment: Thanks. It is my mistake. Flymake is not a major mode, but a minor mode.

Comment: The test here can be shortened to just `(bound-and-true-p flymake-mode)`.

Comment: `M-:` for opening a minibuffer where you can evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use <kbd>M-x describe-mode</kbd> to show all the active minor modes (and major mode) and a brief description of each.

If the minor mode is on in the current buffer, you can find it's name on the popup buffer.